# Force a postback when the back button is pressed

Tags: asp.net, postback, back

I have a webpage with a combo box on the page which is loaded with it's data on the Page_Load event of the page.

From that page I have a link which opens another page (within the same IE window) which allows the user to add/remove items that should appear in the combo.

The problem I have is when the user adds a new item to the combo I need this item to appear in the list on the parent page. However when I click the back button on the browser the Page_Load event on the parent page doesn't fire and the new item isn't loaded into the combo.

Want is the best way to handle this?

I'm using ASP.NET 4.0 and IE9.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using the back button? Can you not implement your own button?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've just done. All working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use javascript and call window.parent.location.refresh() on your new window to force a reload.

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've added my own back button which now does the reload.